# How can I determine if an element exists in an array (perl)

Tags: perl

I'm looping through an array, and I want to test if an element is found in another array.

In pseudo-code, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
foreach $term (@array1) {
    if ($term is found in @array2) { 
        #do something here
    }
}
```

I've got the "foreach" and the "do something here" parts down-pat ... but everything I've tried for the "if term is found in array" test does NOT work ...

I've tried grep:

```
if grep {/$term/} @array2 { #do something }
# this test always succeeds for values of $term that ARE NOT in @array2

if (grep(/$term/, @array2)) { #do something }
# this test likewise succeeds for values NOT IN the array
```

I've tried a couple different flavors of "converting the array to a hash" which many previous posts have indicated are so simple and easy ... and none of them have worked.

I am a long-time low-level user of perl, I understand just the basics of perl, do not understand all the fancy obfuscated code that comprises 99% of the solutions I read on the interwebs ... I would really, truly, honestly appreciate any answers that are explicit in the code and provide a step-by-step explanation of what the code is doing ...

... I seriously don't grok $_ and any other kind or type of hidden, understood, or implied value, variable, or function. I would really appreciate it if any examples or samples have all variables and functions named with clear terms ($term as opposed to $_) ... and describe with comments what the code is doing so I, in all my mentally deficient glory, may hope to possibly understand it some day.  Please.  :-)

...

I have an existing script which uses 'grep' somewhat succesfully:

```
$rc=grep(/$term/, @array);
if ($rc eq 0) { #something happens here }
```

but I applied that EXACT same code to my new script and it simply does NOT succeed properly ... i.e., it "succeeds" (rc = zero) when it tests a value of $term that I know is NOT present in the array being tested.  I just don't get it.

The ONLY difference in my 'grep' approach between 'old' script and 'new' script is how I built the array ... in old script, I built array by reading in from a file:

```
  @array=`cat file`;
```

whereas in new script I put the array inside the script itself (coz it's small) ... like this:

```
  @array=("element1","element2","element3","element4");
```

How can that result in different output of the grep function?  They're both bog-standard arrays!  I don't get it!!!! :-(

########################################################################

#### addendum ... some clarifications or examples of my actual code:

########################################################################

The term I'm trying to match/find/grep is a word element, for example "word123".

This exercise was just intended to be a quick-n-dirty script to find some important info from a file full of junk, so I skip all the niceties (use strict, warnings, modules, subroutines) by choice ... this doesn't have to be elegant, just simple.

The term I'm searching for is stored in a variable which is instantiated via split:

```
foreach $line(@array1) {
  chomp($line);  # habit

  # every line has multiple elements that I want to capture
  ($term1,$term2,$term3,$term4)=split(/\t/,$line);  

  # if a particular one of those terms is found in my other array 'array2'
  if (grep(/$term2/, @array2) { 
    # then I'm storing a different element from the line into a 3rd array which eventually will be outputted
    push(@known, $term1) unless $seen{$term1}++;
  }
}
```

see that grep up there? It ain't workin right ... it is succeeding for all values of $term2 even if it is definitely NOT in array2 ... array1 is a file of a couple thousand lines. The element I'm calling $term2 here is a discrete term that may be in multiple lines, but is never repeated (or part of a larger string) within any given line. Array2 is about a couple dozen elements that I need to "filter in" for my output.

...

I just tried one of the below suggestions:

```
if (grep $_ eq $term2, @array2)
```

And this grep failed for all values of $term2 ... I'm getting an all or nothing response from grep ... so I guess I need to stop using grep. Try one of those hash solutions ... but I really could use more explanation and clarification on those.

Comment: Can you provide a short script (on pastebin or equivalent) that recreates your problem? That would help us diagnose what's going on.

Comment: [How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860226/how-can-i-check-if-a-perl-array-contains-a-particular-value

Comment: Yup... using a hash is the right thing to do here, otherwise your making a solution that won't perform for large arrays (since you're scanning array2 for every element of array1

Comment: What is the value of `$term`? Provide examples of your search term and what you expect to match and not match. Are you seeking an exact match (`"foo"` matches only `"foo"`) or a partial match (`"foo"` matches `"food"`)?

Comment: `@array =\`cat $file\`` is possibly considered a useless use of `cat`. Perl has a perfectly good (better) `open` command to use.

Answer (score 9):

This is in [perlfaq](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays-). A quick way to do it is

```
my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for @array1;
for my $item (@array2) {
    if ($seen{$item}) {
        # item is in array2, do something
    }
}
```

If letter case is not important, you can set the keys with `$seen{ lc($_) }` and check with `if ($seen{ lc($item) })`.

**ETA:**

With the changed question: If the task is to match single words in `@array2` against whole lines in `@array1`, the task is more complicated. Trying to split the lines and match against hash keys will likely be unsafe, because of punctuation and other such things. So, a regex solution will likely be the safest.

Unless `@array2` is *very* large, you might do something like this:

```
my $rx = join "|", @array2;
for my $line (@array1) {
    if ($line =~ /\b$rx\b/) {  # use word boundary to avoid partial matches
        # do something
    }
}
```

If `@array2` contains meta characters, such as `*?+|`, you have to make sure they are escaped, in which case you'd do something like:

```
my $rx = join "|", map quotemeta, @array2;
# etc
```

Comment: The advantage of this is that it's O(N). The naive solution is O(N^2). choroba's and cdarke's are O(N^2).

Comment: I don't think this example will work as is, and I don't understand it well enough to see how it could be modified to suit. Array1 is the contents of a file, with each element of the array being an entire line from the file -- a row of data comprised of multiple elements. I have to chop that up to get the individual elements that I need to test against array2 which is a simpler array comprised of a plain list of single words. I can't compare an entire line from array1 against the single words in array2, that won't work.

Comment: @user1505587 You should have mentioned that in your question, it's a fairly important piece of information. So I take it then that you also want to ignore letter case. I will add the fix.

Comment: If you just want to find a list of words in a file, and you want a quick and dirty solution, why are you not just using `grep` with the `-f` option?

Comment: @TLP ... case is unimportant. And I don't think the source of the datasets is too important either since all data is reduced to arrays and elements (scalar vars). I have the element in hand, it is $term. I want to find IF $term exists in Array2. I don't need to pull anything out of Array2, this is an existence check only. If $term exists in Array2, then I have to do some work on the line that $term came out of (i.e., the original element form Array1). That also is already done, and not in question.

Comment: I just wanted to do all my work in one script. Grepping against the file outside of the perl script doesn't put the file data into the perl script where I want to manipulate it. I spose I could reduce the initial file using for i in list do grep $i oldfile >>newfile done, then all data in newfile would be relevant and I could run my perl script against that file and skip the grep-in-perl issue entirely. But that's at least one more step than I wanted to execute. Two scripts instead of one. No, perl is sposed to do the work, not me.

Comment: Oh, and the question didn't change, just your understanding of it ;-) ... I'm still just trying to see if an element stored as a scalar var is present in an array :-)

Comment: @MuleHeadJoe Since I can't read your mind, I would not know that you are looking for a substring and not an exact match. The details determine the solution, and the fewer details you give, the less accurate the answers will be. A quick and dirty solution would be to run the `grep` in a capture, such as `qx()`. But I did offer you a perl solution that should work in my update.

Comment: Since you are just looking for existence, check List::Util and List::MoreUtils - one of them provides an `any` function that will give you the benefit of bailing out once it hits a match.

Comment: @TLP thank you for all the information and suggestions. I'm still learning stuff here even if not all the suggestions work perfectly for my situation, and I appreciate you taking the time to post solutions and discuss it with me :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the (infamous) "smart match" operator, provided you are on 5.10 or later:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw/a b c d e f g h/; 
my @array2 = qw/a c e g z/; 

print "a in \@array1\n" if 'a' ~~ @array1;
print "z in \@array1\n" if 'z' ~~ @array1;
print "z in \@array2\n" if 'z' ~~ @array2;
```

The example is very simple, but you can use an RE if you need to as well.
I should add that not everyone likes ~~ because there are some ambiguities and, um, "undocumented features".  Should be OK for this though.

Comment: I tried this:

    if ($term1 ~~ @array2) {
      print "$term found in array2\n";
    }

Comment: sorry, got distracted mid-comment and it timed out on me ... but I was trying to use that indicated 'smart match operator' but it did not work for me.  I'm using perl 5.10.1 on Cygwin. No errors, just didn't provide expected results.

Comment: @MuleHeadJoe - RE -> regular expression.  I prefer cdarke's smart match solution.  Am unsure, though, why it didn't work for you.  For example, using cdarke's arrays: `do{print "$_ found in \@array2\n" if $_ ~~ @array2} for @array1;` shows a, c, e, g in @array2

Comment: @MuleheadJoe - RE: either Religous Education or Regular Expression.  I guess you need to figure out which is appropriate for the context.

Comment: @Kenosis:  Your results for that test appear to be correct to me, what else would you expect?  a,c,e,g are all in both `@array1` and `@array2` (z is in `@array2` but not in `@array1`).

Comment: @cdarke: Indeed, and I wanted to share this with MuleHeadJoe, as I prefer your smart matching solution for his "test if an element is found in another array" case.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw/a b c d e f g h/;
my @array2 = qw/a c e g z/;

for my $term (@array1) {
    if (grep $_ eq $term, @array2) {
        print "$term found.\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a found.
c found.
e found.
g found.
```

Comment: The OP is doing regex matches, not exact matches. But it's not clear what type of match he/she really wants.

Comment: Is there a reason your example uses "for" and not "foreach"? Is it personal preference or is there a technical reason? In my script I use "foreach $line(@array1)" ... my array1 is a text file that I'm reading in (@array1=\`cat myfile\`;), chopping up each line so I can reorder elements and eventually output everything as a csv file that I can open & manipulate in Excel.

Comment: `for` and `foreach` are synonymous - use whichever you find to be more expressive.

Comment: @RickF ... thanks, I thought they had different features. I rarely if ever use 'for' so wasn't sure.

Comment: I think foreach was an accident in the design of an otherwise good language. What else could explain it? Many other languages uses for so I think for is clearer than foreach. (I addition to being shorter)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@ar = ( '1','2','3','4','5','6','10' );
@arr = ( '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' ) ;

foreach $var ( @arr ){
    print "$var not found\n " if ( ! ( grep /$var/, @ar )) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching is the most efficient way of matching elements. This would do the trick. Cheers!

```
print "$element found in the array\n" if ("@array" =~ m/$element/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'actual code' shouldn't even compile:

```
if (grep(/$term2/, @array2) {
```

should be:

```
if (grep (/$term2/, @array2)) {
```

You have unbalanced parentheses in your code. You may also find it easier to use grep with a callback (code reference) that operates on its arguments (the array.) It helps keep the parenthesis from blurring together. This is optional, though. It would be:

```
if (grep {/$term2/} @array2) {
```

You may want to use strict; and use warnings; to catch issues like this.

Comment: my bad, I'm not cutting/pasting code ... code is on a physically separate machine ... the real deal had matched parens, and in that world I always check for syntax errors by doing "perl -cw [scriptname]" ...

Answer (score 0):

The example below might be helpful, it tries to see if any element in @array_sp is present in @my_array:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

@my_array = qw(20001 20003);

@array_sp = qw(20001 20002 20004);
print "@array_sp\n";

foreach $case(@my_array){
    if("@array_sp" =~ m/$case/){
    print "My God!\n";
    }

}
```

use pattern matching can solve this. Hope it helps
-QC

Answer (score 0):

```
1. grep with eq , then 
    if (grep {$_ eq $term2} @array2) { 
    print "$term2 exists in the array";
    }

2. grep with regex , then 
    if (grep {/$term2/} @array2) {
    print "element with pattern $term2 exists in the array";
    }
```