# How to identify a variable whether it belongs to one array or another in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a Perl array contains a particular value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860226/how-can-i-check-if-a-perl-array-contains-a-particular-value)

I have two arrays `@array1 = (1..26);`, `@array2 = ('a'..'z');` and a variable `$x`. suppose `$x=5` then how can I compare this value with two arrays and state in output that this variable belongs to `@array1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the controversial smart-match operator, you can use `grep`.

```
say   grep { $x eq $_ } @array1 ? "first"
    : grep { $x eq $_ } @array2 ? "second"
    : "none";
```

You should be using hashes here if you do this repeatedly.

```
my %array1 = map { $_ => 1 } @array1;
my %array2 = map { $_ => 1 } @array2;

say   $array1{$x} ? "first"
    : $array2{$x} ? "second"
    : "none";
```

Comment: Note: `grep` will check every element instead of stopping asap, but that's rarely a concern.

Comment: [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils)'s `any` function could replace `grep` here. But if efficiency is an issue, than clearly the hash version outperforms everything because hash lookups take constant time.

Answer (score 5):

Perl 5.10 and greater has a new smart match operator that makes easy work of this task:

```
if ($x ~~ @array1) {
  say '$x is in @array1';
}
elsif ($x ~~ @array2) {
  say '$x is in @array2';
}
else {
  say '$x is not in either array.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the smartmatch:

```
say   $x ~~ \@array1 ? 'first'
    : $x ~~ \@array2 ? 'second'
    : 'none';
```