# Perl: If statement with or ignores if statement altogether

Tags: perl, if-statement

Here is my line of code:

```
#!/usr loca/bin/perl                                                           
use warnings;                                                                   
use strict;  
...
...
if ($file ne "." || $file ne "..")
```

I have also tried:

```
if ($file ne "." or $file ne "..")
```

And the if statement always passes since it cannot recognize the conditions I am setting. I have done one at a time and they work as expected. Can anyone help determine how I need to set this up properly? Thanks!

Comment: No, it always passes because both of your conditions cannot be false simultaneously. Try using `&&/and` instead of `||/or` and see if your are more satisfied with the results.

Comment: This looks like an AND condition: `&&`.

Comment: Here's a list of things that are not equal to `.`: `foo`, `1`, `..`. Here's a list of things that are not equal to `..`: `bar`, `2`, `.`. Here's a list of things that are in either the first list *or* the second list: `foo`, `bar`, `1`, `2`, `.`, `..`. In other words, everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everything* is either not a single dot or not a double dot!

You mean

```
if ( $file ne "." and $file ne ".." ) { ... }
```

and you should probably be looking at `glob` rather than `opendir` / `readdir`

Comment: Globbing is not necessarily better, especially for [portability](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html): "Don't count on filename globbing. Use `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` instead."

Comment: recommend using `&&`, not `and`, and reserving `and`for flow control

Comment: Thanks, simple logic oversight on my end that was probably not worthy of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @lchristina26 It's actually a very common mistake. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29944441/176646), for example (possible duplicate?). Wrapping your brain around multiple negatives at once is tough; I prefer statements like `next if $file eq '.' || $file eq '..';` since they're easier to understand at a glance.