# How to split string by comma into a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
my @logs = split(",",$opts->{"logs"});
$opt_href->{"logs"} = \@logs;
```

It basically splits the `$opts->{"logs"}` by comma and keeps the array ref. Later I need to check if string exists in the  `$opt_href->{"logs"}` array. Looking at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860226/how-can-i-check-if-a-perl-array-contains-a-particular-value), I see that it's recommended to keep a hash, instead of array. I could just do:

```
my %logs;
for each my $log (split(",",$opts->{"logs"})) {
    $logs{$log} = 1;
}
$opt_href->{"logs"} = \%logs;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a one/two liners?

Comment: Re "*I see that it's recommended to keep a hash*", Not quite. A hash was recommended to implement a set. Are you trying to form a set from the values in `$opts->{logs}`?

Comment: I agree with ikegami that it is not at all certain you need a hash. Especially with strings in manually edited option files. A hash will differentiate between `foo ` and `foo` and `FOO`, whereas for example a regex match can be made less strict. It all depends on what is important to your code. Checking a hash key vs looping through an array is a minor optimization in most cases.

Comment: @TLP They say that they "_need to check if string exists..._" and it seems that that's why they decided for a hash, as an efficient and handy look-up structure.  This is then indeed a good solution, while I agree that it is not clear from the question whether that's the best way to organize data. (But that's not what they are asking so that's OK)

Answer (score 5):

```
my %logs = map { $_ => 1 } split /,/, $opts->{logs};
$opt_href->{logs} = \%logs;
```

Or, using the anonymous hash reference, constructed by `{ }`

```
$opt_href->{logs} = { map { $_ => 1 } split /,/, $opts->{logs} };
```

Comment: "_anonymous hash reference, constructed by `{ }`_"  --- to be more precise, the `{}` constructs an anonymous hash and returns a reference to it